# why is this jquery text toggle not working?

Tags: jquery

Ok not sure whats going on the code does toggle class, but when you click it again it is well seen that the class is removed however the text remains the same "Locked..." and is not changed back to the original.

Here is the jQuery code

```
$("#sprv").click(function() {
                 $(this).toggleClass('btn_active');

                 $(".prv").text("Make private?");

                 }, function(){

                 $(this).toggleClass('btn_active');

                 $(".prv").text("Locked...");
});

<span class="prv">Make private?</span>
```

Can some one tell me what I am doing wrong and how to fix this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing two functions into the click handler. You can't do that (it is interpreting the first function as the eventdata, and the second function as the handler -- see http://api.jquery.com/click/). You need to pass just one event handler. It can deal with both cases though, like this:

```
$('#sprv').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('btn_active');
    $('.prv').text($(this).hasClass('btn_active') ? 'Locked...' : 'Make private?');
});
```

First it toggles the class, then it uses [jQuery.hasClass()](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) to determine if it has the `btn_active` class. It always updates the text, but it uses a value according to the state (determined from the just-toggled class).

Comment: a, works just fine. thanks :) should give documentation a read few more times. sadly i use long long long jQuery to make majority of my stuff so not really good with shorten ways. but should learn would make life easier

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).

Try this:

```
 $("#sprv").toggle(function() {
    $(".prv").text("Locked...");

 }, function(){ 
    $(".prv").text("Make private?");
 });
```

With the html:

```
<input type="button" id="sprv" value="clickme" />  
<span class="prv">Make private?</span>
```

Comment: *Dur*. Meant to up-vote, clicked the wrong arrow. Sorry about that. Fixed it.

Comment: I think your answer is actually better than mine and should be the accepted answer.